Excel - Pass Multiple Arguments to a Function as a Single String
I'm grasping for straws with this one.
Is it possible to force an Excel formula to process a string as a comma delimiter?
For example, in
=COUNTIF(range, criteria)

pass [$A$1:$A$10, "apple"] as range and criteria as a single string or array. I've tried using TEXTSPLIT() and INDIRECT() to no avail. Would there happen to be a DELIMITER() function that I just haven't heard about?
In other words, is there a way to force Excel formulas to recognize "," as a delimiter in some way, or pass an array of arguments that circumvent Excel's comma requirement?
As to why, my company uses an Excel add-in with its own functions that unfortunately cannot be recognized or called in the Excel Labs environment. In my use case, I have one such that takes 6 required parameters, that I would like to pass a single argument to, in the form of a custom lambda function. This immensely improves user-friendliness for a huge amount of applications within my company.

AFAIK, no this isn't possible with native formulas. This won't work with a function coming from an add-in either.

Are you thinking something like: =LET(z,"$A$1:$A$10,apple",y,TEXTSPLIT(z,,","),COUNTIF(INDIRECT(TAKE(y,1)),TAKE(y,-1)))?

@ScottCraner trying to avoid this use case since it means passing 12 variables as opposed to 1 or 6. The native formula reads like: =LVCELL("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6"). I cannot create a lambda =LV(_cell) since I cannot call LVCELL from inside Labs, nor can I use =LVCELL(LV("var1"), LV("var2"), LV("var3"), LV("var4"), LV("var5"), LV("var6")) since Excel Labs does not recognize the address of the cell that called it. If it could, I could identify the 6 variables by sheet position. At a minimum, I see =LVCELL(LV("var1", $A$1), LV("var2", $A$1), etc... with 12 input variables.

Then I agree, there is not a native formula that will do this.

Can you create a named function and call it say EVAL? Make it something like =LAMBDA(X,EVALUATE(x)), a shot in the dark to be honest as I have not tried anything like it. Now call it with =EVAL("COUNTIF("&Your string&")")

@JvdV This is exactly what I was hoping to hear when I posted this question, haha. I thought about this but have no idea how to call a function as a string. As far as I've figured, the definition of EVALUATE either manually reinvents the function or calls it directly.

@JvdV wait wait wait... EVALUATE() is a thing?? I think this might actually work! https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Right, have a go with this:

Step 1: Create a named function in the name manager making use of the ancient Excel 4.0 Macro function EVALUATE():

Step 2: Now, call it using for example:


Please don't mind my semi-colons since I have a Dutch installment of Excel. Just swap these out for the comma's.
Also note that for me it only worked when I removed the space in front op "apple".
And a final note; this workbook will now have to be saved with macro's enabled (".xlsm")!

Absolutely brilliant; makes two prior impossibilities possible. It can be typed directly into Excel Labs, avoiding name manager, and play into more complex functions. It can also be called anonymously, if you know how to do that.
EVAL =
LAMBDA(x,
LET(
y, """apple""" & "&" & """banana""",
EVALUATE(y)
)
);
You gave me news that both made and ruined my weekend at 5pm on a Friday. It's amazingly powerful (once you get the hang of all the quotation marks) and works in both my use cases described above with the Add-In. My only dilemma: WHY XLSM

This is going to become a corporate nightmare for me. Don't know if I should pretend I never saw this...

@ProdigusProgrammer I'm both happy and sorry I made and ruined your weekend!

In recent versions of Excel, you'll find function TEXTSPLIT().
In cell A1 enter a,b,123.45,b,c and in B1 =TEXTSPLIT(A1,",").
Values in B1, C1, D1, E1 can be used in other functions
e.g. =CONCAT(UPPER(B1),UPPER(C1),UPPER(E1),TEXT(D1,"00000.000")) is the formula in B2 below
You'll probably have to read up on functions that "spill"... [O365Support][2]

In B2 =LET(vals,TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),MATCH("b",vals,0))

Note that B2 does not depend on A2. The formula in A2 shows a spilled range, the formula in B2 shows how to use spilling inside a formula (without affecting neighbouring cells).

My question is to remove the commas you used in the CONCAT() formula to separate the parameters and still achieve the same result. Thank you, though
